# split dataframe and write new csv's based on loop

Tags: python, csv, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
Allotment   Year    NDVI     A_Annex    Bachelor
A_Annex     1984    1.0      0.40       0.60
A_Annex     1984    1.5      0.56       0.89
A_Annex     1984    2.0      0.78       0.76
A_Annex     1985    3.4      0.89       0.54
A_Annex     1985    1.6      0.98       0.66
A_Annex     1986    2.5      1.10       0.44
A_Annex     1986    1.7      0.87       0.65
```

and I want to write each column to a new dataframe, and a subsequent csv based on the column name.  So I want a new csv for the contents of each column.

so far I have done this:

```
outpath='C:\'
for column in df:
    x=pd.DataFrame(df[column])
    outpath=outpath + column + '.csv'
    x.to_csv(outpath)
```

but `column` contains every single column name, when I only want to write to separate ones.  My desired file names would be something like `Allotment.csv`, `Year.csv`, `NDVI.csv`, `A_Annex.csv`, `Bachelor.csv`

Comment: I won't add an answer since you already accepted one, but you could do this in one line:  `for column in df:  df[column].to_csv( 'C:\' + column + '.csv')`

Comment: ah, good to know and much simpler, thank you.  Just curious, if I wanted two send to columns at once to a new csv how would I do this?  e.g. If I wanted to send `Year` and `A_Annex` together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is collecting all the column names:

```
outpath = outpath + column + '.csv'
```

because it is run on every loop of the for loop

This works:

```
outpath='C:\'
for column in df:
     x=pd.DataFrame(df[column])
     outfile=outpath + column + '.csv'
     x.to_csv(outfile)
```

Notice the loop variable name is changed from `outpath` to a new var `outfile` which will prevent the filenames from being aggregated and mangled.

I noted the `.csv` files have two columns, the row number and the value.
If you don't want the row numbers, use `x.to_csv(outfile, index=False)`